# Is it possible to make little changes to the FEN diagram

Tags: discussion, feature-request, pgn-viewer

Consider the following games:

- [This game](http://dpaste.com/1311630/plain/) was played on chess.com
- [This game](http://dpaste.com/1311636/plain/) was played on Shredder engine software.

The chess.com game will perfectly work if you just use

```
[FEN ""]
and past it here, it will work
```

But Shredder won't work, because the FEN is formatted differently, on separate lines. So in order to past that on this site you have to manually remove all the lines.

So is it possible to do like `preformatted text editor option` which auto indent. Could we make the `[FEN ""]` accept all kind of FENs as long as they are indented or something.

So that this would be valid

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 {0s} Nf6 {+0.06/5 0s} 2. Nf3 {28s} d5 {+0.12/13 0s} 
3. Bf4 {24s} Bf5 {+0.18/12 0s} 4. e3 {31s} e6 {+0.18/12 1s} 
5. Bd3 {34s} Bxd3 {+0.10/12 0s} 6. Qxd3 {12s} Bd6 {+0.11/12 
0s} 7. Nbd2 {37s (O-O)} O-O {+0.04/9 1s} 8. O-O {24:11m} 
Bxf4 {0.00/17 1s} 9. exf4 {22s} Qd6 {+0.08/12 0s} 10. f5 
{28s} exf5 {0.00/13 0s} 11. Qxf5 {13s} Nc6 {+0.04/13 0s} 
12. Rfe1 {33s} Rfe8 {0.00/13 0s} 13. c3 {21s} Ne7 {+0.07/12 
0s} 14. Qe5 {44s (Qh3)} Qb6 {-0.04/10 1s} 15. Rab1 {1:15m 
(b3)} Ng6 {-0.11/10 2s} 16. Qg3 {27s} Rac8 {-0.08/12 0s} 
17. Ne5 {36s (Qh3)} Re6 {-0.07/9 1s} 18. Nxg6 {18s} hxg6 
{-0.06/14 0s} 19. Re5 {16s} Rce8 {-0.17/14 0s} 20. Rxe6 
{31s} Rxe6 {-0.21/15 0s} 21. Qd3 {16s} Qd6 {-0.11/14 0s} 
22. Nf3 {1:04m} Qf4 {-0.06/14 0s} 23. Re1 {45s} Rxe1+ 
{-0.14/14 0s} 24. Nxe1 {12s} Qc1 {-0.04/14 0s} 25. Qe2 
{32s} g5 {0.00/14 0s} 26. h3 {16s} Ne4 {+0.02/14 0s} 27. g4 
{28s} c5 {+0.05/15 0s} 28. dxc5 {1:00m} Nxc5 {+0.09/12 1s} 
29. Qe8+ {17s} Kh7 {+0.01/16 0s} 30. Kg2 {44s} Qb1 
{+0.01/16 0s} 31. Nf3 {37s} f6 {+0.01/16 0s} 32. b4 {21s} 
Nd3 {0.00/17 0s} 33. Qh5+ {1:01m} Kg8 {0.00/20 0s} 34. Qe8+ 
{23s} Kh7 {0.00/19 0s} 35. Qh5+ {52s} Kg8 {0.00/20 0s} 
36. Qe8+ {6s} Kh7 {0.00/99 0s} 1/2-1/2
```

I used the [FEN ""] and the `preformatted text option`

Each engine/website has a different method to export the game, that way all the FENs from any engine will be accepted without reformatting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. I just tried inputting the block you have above (after "So that this would be valid"), and it seemed to render just fine. Line breaks aren't generally a problem for the site's PGN viewer.

Comment: @EdDean when i asked [this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/is-it-possible-to-expect-different-results-from-computer-vs-same-computer-on-the)  i had to remove all the line breaks in order for the shredder game to be shown on the viewer

Comment: Hmm, I had tested out an edit on that post (without saving the edit) where I just dropped in the above text without removing line breaks, and it was working. I just tried again and saved the edit, so you can see whether that's what you wanted or not.

Comment: @EdDean i can't create diagrams here, please see my question again, and see what happens if i just past the FN without editing it http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/is-it-possible-to-expect-different-results-from-computer-vs-same-computer-on-the

Comment: please delete my edit to that question after you see it, i had to post it there, i can't post FEN here for some reason

Comment: Yeah, the viewer is only active on the main site, not on meta.

Comment: I just rolled back your latest edit, and I now know what the issue you were having is, as well as the solution. If you paste in the game as you did in your last edit, all you'd need to do to make it display correctly is to highlight the whole text of the game, and then click the pre-formatted text button in the post editor. That will automatically indent all of the text, and the viewer will display it correctly. Try that out and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @EdDean Yes it worked! thanks