# Instructions to post a game in the Help, FAQ, or even WYSIWIG editor

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've been trying to implement a nice diagram and have no idea how.

Based on [Is it possible to make little changes to the FEN diagram](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244/is-it-possible-to-make-little-changes-to-the-fen-diagram) I tried

[FEN ""]
1k1r3r/pPbn4/4p3/8/3Pp1B1/2q3pP/2P1Q1P1/R3K2R w KQ -

Which doesn't work. I looked at the Help and there are no instructions. To attract new users I think you all should strongly consider either adding it to the FAQ, Help, or possibly an extra button on the WYSIWIG Editor so people like me can figure out how to post games.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick things that might help:

1. The diagrams only work on the main site, nothing will show up on meta here
2. In order to show just a diagram (no moves), enter just the FEN string in a code block
   `1k1r3r/pPbn4/4p3/8/3Pp1B1/2q3pP/2P1Q1P1/R3K2R w KQ - 0 1`

As a side note, the FEN string you posted is missing the move counters.  It should have two numbers at the end (`0` and `1` above) that represent the number of half moves towards the 50 move rule and the game's move number respectively.

Hopefully that gets a working diagram for you!

Comment: Hmm I copy and pasted the exact FEN code that Chess.com had next to my game so not sure why something would be missing. How do you post with moves? As I see you're a community moderator what are your feelings on adding this information somewhere easier to find?

Comment: @Ryan I definitely think we could do a better job making some or all of this easier (especially for visitors who aren't used to Stack Exchange).  I'm honestly not sure if there's a good place for it on the help page or in the help center, I'll take a look around a bit later.

Comment: To add the moves to a post see the directions [in this FAQ post](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/179/12).

Comment: Hmm I had tried that as well, read that line breaks shouldn't effect it. Maybe I'll try again removing the line breaks and see if it works.

Comment: Nope, not a clue. Maybe you could take a look and tell me what went wrong: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/is-there-a-name-for-the-a-position-where-king-is-on-the-first-last-row-and-an-en

Comment: @Ryan Oh I think the problem is that the pgn isn't in a code block.  Highlight all of the pgn (from [FEN ""] to the last move) and press `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Ya, you all definitely need to find a place for this in a FAQ or something! Thanks for the help at least